# Unwanted newline appearing

Tags: c, loops, random, newline

Whenever I run my program, it doesn't start printing the asterisks until after a newline, why?
Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int createRow = 0,
        createCol;

    while (createRow <= 5)
    {
        while (createCol <= ((createRow * 2) - 1))
        {
            printf("*");
            createCol++;
        }
        createCol = 1;
        createRow++;

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
*************
***************
*****************
*******************
```

As you see, right before the very first asterisk, there is a newline. How do I fix this?

Comment: eh the newline didnt show up here but there is one before the first astrisk

Comment: Q: Did you forget to initialize createCol?

Comment: change `printf("\n");` to `createRow==1 ?: printf("\n");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it by changing

```
printf("\n");
```

to

```
createRow == 1 ?: printf("\n");
```

---

This is the same as the following, but is more concise and makes sense to a programmer who knows how to use the `ternary operator`.

```
if (createRow != 1) {
   printf("\n");
}
```

When using the ternary operator `condition ? expression1 : expression2;` **expression1** is not required but **expression2** is. `Expression1` executes if the condition is true and `expression2` executes if the condition is false.

Comment: @Jongware ... Misuse of the ternary operator? I don't find this use of the ternary operator to be esoteric, and it's more concise than an if statement.

Comment: As long as he understands what the ternary operator is and how it works, it's better that he be exposed to good examples of its use (short one liners like this) rather than chained expressions. @Jongware

Answer (score 3):

`createCol` is uninitialized and used before it is assigned a value.

Do the following changes

```
int createRow = 1,
    createCol = 0;  

while (createRow <= 5)
{
    while (createCol <= ((createRow * 2)-1))
    {
       //Loop body
    }
    createCol = 0;
    // Rest of the code
}
```